# Only create directory for a certain install (feature) level

Tags: directory, wix, installation, windows-installer

I am creating an msi with WiX. I only want to create certain directories if the install level is higher than 1. Here is my Directory structure:

```
<!--DIRECTORIES-->
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="Product" />
    <Directory Id="Documents" Name="Documents">
      <Directory Id="Help" Name="Help" />
      <Directory Id="Other" Name="Other" />
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
    <Directory Id="Shortcuts" Name="Product">
      <Directory Id="DocumentShortcuts" Name="Documents">
        <Directory Id="HelpShortcut" Name="Help"/>
        <Directory Id="OtherShortcut" Name="Other"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

I only want the "DocumentShortcuts" directory to be created on the start menu if the install level is above 1. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directory elements only define directory structure not any instructions that they should be created.   Windows Installer only creates directories when needed:

1. A file is being installed to a directory (Component and File elements)
2. The installer is explicitly told to create the directory (Component and CreateFolder elements)
3. A sub directory needs to be created for reasons 1 and/or 2.

The component elements that contain said resources then needs to be linked to Feature elements using the ComponentRef element ( or indirectly through ComponentGroup and ComponentGroupRef elements).

Comment: Ok, so my problem wasn't actually a problem...
Thanks a lot for the clarification